# Problema para sincronizar Gradle en Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, programación-móvil

Acabo de instalar Android Studio 2.3 y al crear un nuevo proyecto me da el siguiente error con gradle. Ya logre descargar manualmente pero igual me sigue dando el mismo error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
```

También eliminé la dependencia

```
junit:junit:4.12
```

Y se la descargué manualmente porque mi conexión a internet no es buena.

Comment: El proyecto que intentas crear no es de Android!

Comment: Lo unico diferente que hice fue agregar un SDK de las versiones anteriores porque no puedo descargarlas de internet.

Answer (score 1):

**Estas usando clases que no son de Android SDK, por esa razón no pueden ser resueltas.**

```
Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
```

El proyecto que intentas crear no puede usar una o varias clases que definiste.

De hecho aquí hay una respuesta del señor Mark Murphy acerca de esto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561319/importing-javax-packages-in-android